# pandas faster series of lists unrolling for one-hot encoding?

Tags: pandas, one-hot-encoding

I'm reading from a database that had many array type columns, which pd.read_sql gives me a dataframe with columns that are `dtype=object`, containing lists.

I'd like an efficient way to find which rows have arrays containing some element:

```
s = pd.Series(
    [[1,2,3], [1,2], [99], None, [88,2]]
)
print s
```

..

```
0    [1, 2, 3]
1       [1, 2]
2         [99]
3         None
4      [88, 2]
```

1-hot-encoded feature tables for an ML application and I'd like to end up with tables like:

```
   contains_1 contains_2, contains_3 contains_88
0  1          ...
1  1
2  0
3  nan
4  0
...
```

I can unroll a series of arrays like so:

```
s2 = s.apply(pd.Series).stack()

0  0     1.0
   1     2.0
   2     3.0
1  0     1.0
   1     2.0
2  0    99.0
4  0    88.0
   1     2.0
```

which gets me at the being able to find the elements meeting some test:

```
>>> print s2[(s2==2)].index.get_level_values(0)
Int64Index([0, 1, 4], dtype='int64')
```

Woot! This step:

```
s.apply(pd.Series).stack()
```

produces a great intermediate data-structure (s2) that's fast to iterate over for each category. However, the `apply` step is jaw-droppingly slow (many 10's of seconds for a single column with 500k rows with lists of 10's of items), and I have many columns.

---

Update: It seems likely that having the data in a series of lists to begin with in quite slow. Performing unroll in the SQL side seems tricky (I have many columns that I want to unroll). Is there a way to pull array data into a better structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import cytoolz

s0 = s.dropna()
v = s0.values.tolist()
i = s0.index.values
l = [len(x) for x in v]
c = cytoolz.concat(v)
n = np.append(0, np.array(l[:-1])).cumsum().repeat(l)
k = np.arange(len(c)) - n

s1 = pd.Series(c, [i.repeat(l), k])
```

UPDATE: What worked for me...

```
def unroll(s):
    s = s.dropna()
    v = s.values.tolist()
    c = pd.Series(x for x in cytoolz.concat(v)) # 16 seconds!
    i = s.index
    lens = np.array([len(x) for x in v]) #s.apply(len) is slower
    n = np.append(0, lens[:-1]).cumsum().repeat(lens)
    k = np.arange(sum(lens)) - n

    s = pd.Series(c)
    s.index = [i.repeat(lens), k]

    s = s.dropna()
    return s
```

It should be possible to replace:

```
    s = pd.Series(c)
    s.index = [i.repeat(lens), k]
```

with:

```
        s = pd.Series(c, index=[i.repeat(lens), k])
```

But this doesn't work. (Says is ok [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html) )

Comment: Thanks -- I've added a couple of tweaks. And put into your answer. cytoolz.concat is an order or magnitude faster that .apply(Series), but is still ~16 seconds per column for my application.