# pandas.read_sql read array columns directly into native structures?

Tags: pandas

Is there any way to get pandas to read a table with array-typed columns directly into native structures? By default, a `int[]` column ends up as an object column containing python list of python ints. There are [ways to convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44813885/pandas-faster-series-of-lists-unrolling-for-one-hot-encoding/44814760#44814760) this into a column of Series, or better, a column with a multi-index, but this are very slow (~10 seconds) for 500M rows. Would be much faster if the data was originally loaded into a dataframe. I don't what to unroll the array in sql because I have very many array columns.

```
url = "postgresql://u:p@host:5432/dname"
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(url)

df = pd.read_sql_query("select 1.0 as a, 2.2 as b, array[1,2,3] as c;", engine)
print df
print type(df.loc[0,'c'])  # list
print type(df.loc[0,'c'][0])  # int
```

Answer (score 1):

[Does it help](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14314#issuecomment-250153594) if you use `read_sql_table` instead of `read_sql_query` ? Also, type detection can fail due to missing values. Maybe this is the cause.